# Docker Toolbox - hang on `docker push`

Tags: docker, docker-toolbox

I am using Docker Toolbox on Mac.

`docker push` is hanging.  How do I hard restart the daemon or docker-machine VM to get this unhung in a bad manner.  It is taking too long to wait for it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just run:

```
docker-machine stop <name-of-your-docker-machine>
```

which is usually:

```
docker-machine stop default
```

next option:

```
docker-machine kill default
```

Did you check that your `docker machine` is running:

```
docker-machine ls
```

Brute force approach:

```
kill -9 `ps -Af | grep -v grep | grep VBoxHeadless | awk '{print $2}'`
```